# Jquery animate run twice after click

Tags: jquery

i have a problem with jquery animate.
my situation is here:

HTML:

```
<span class="button">click</span>
<div class="submenu">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="parent">
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li class="back-to-category">
            <span>back</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Lvl2 Item 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Lvl2 Item 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Lvl2 Item 1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button {
  background:black;
  color:white;
  padding:1em;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.submenu {
  display:none;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
}
ul.menu > li {
  background:#ccc;
}
.submenu li > div {
  background:#eee;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:100%;
  width:100%;
}
.submenu .back-to-category {
  background:red;

}
```

script:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
  $(".submenu").slideToggle("slow");
});
$(".submenu ul.menu > li.parent").click(function() {
  $(this).children("div").animate({
    "left": "0%"
});
});
$(".submenu .back-to-category").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent("div").animate({
    "left": "100%"
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/caesarSK/0g9nfnq8/2/

I have a link in the main menu (click button). When I click on this link, my submenu slideDown. after another click on submenu item (Item 1), level 2 submenu slide from left (animate left 0%). To this step it's okay.
In submenu level 2 I have a back button. After click on this button, submenu level 2 must be hidden (animate left 100%).
But when I click the back button, submenu level 2 slide to left (left 0% - this is ok) and immediately returns to the position, which of course I do not want.

What am I doing wrong that you will not leave the menu hidden after clicking the back button?

thx for help

Comment: The code you have until now will help. Maybe on https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: show us your code...

Comment: sorry, I edited the post. Now its ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nothing wrong in your code. Its just due to event bubbling the other click event is getting triggered when you click on back button

[**Working JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0g9nfnq8/3/)

You just need to use `e.stopPropagation();` in your click event

```
$(".submenu .back-to-category").click(function(e) { console.log('c');
  $(this).parent().parent("div").animate({
    "left": "100%"
  });
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

> **event.stopPropagation()**
>
> **Description:** Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree,
>   preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event. [**read more**](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use style left? You can do easy with `.hide()` and `.show()`

for example:

```
$(".submenu .back-to-category").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent("div").hide({
  });
});
```

This will work once, for the complete script you need to edit all the functions, maybe this will help you a lot:

[jQuery Hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

[jQuery Show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Comment: thx you for answer, but I want use left. Can you help me in this case?